# Manipulating 2D Lighting with editor version 2021.2.19f1 with C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, lighting

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong, but I am currently having an issue manipulating the 2D lighting of objects. Everything looks normal in visual studio, no errors, but when I try to initialize the code in Unity, it errors out and says the object doesn't have Light on it. 2d lighting seems to be a script, instead of a different type of object like with 3d lighting, but I can't reference the script. It's very hard to find info on this because it seems like the URP gets updated very regularly, and nothing I've found explains what I need to do to manipulate the settings like intensity.

Does anyone have any advice for me?

Answer (score 0):

First create a new 2D light by going to Light < 2D < Point Light 2D (You can use any Light).

Now you should have a 2D light in your scene. Next attach a script to the light for example LightManipulator.cs.

Inside of LightManipulator.cs you can now reference the 2D light by declaring it as a `public variable`.

`public Light2D light;`

You can now change various values of this light. For example setting the intensity to 0.5f.

`light.intensity = 0.5f;`

EDIT: You have to import this at the top `using UnityEngine.Experimental.Rendering.Universal;`

Comment: Wow, that's so obvious, Thank you so so so much, I was stalled on the game I am working on because of that!

Comment: So this is what I get when I try that:

https://i.imgur.com/hcstS7M.png

Comment: Add this at the top of your script: `using UnityEngine.Experimental.Rendering.Universal;`